# SQL - Identifying Companies who Drop in Score

Tags: sql

I'm working with a table with companyID, score, and timestamp.

Running SELECT produces a list of customers and their changing scores over time, here's an example restricted to one companyID:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/f09aD.png

I want to produce a list of all companyIDs whose score has dropped x% over the two most recent timestamps, but I'm relatively new to SQL and unsure how to achieve this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Which SQL are you using? MySQL, Microsoft?

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT companyProfileId, engagementScore, row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY companyProfileId ORDER BY createTimeStamp Desc) AS rowNum
FROM _yourTable_) AS foo
WHERE foo.rowNum() <= 2
AND engagementScore * X = y
```

[over Clause mssql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql) Hopefully you are using mssql, as this wont work on other rdbms's

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative solution tested in MS SQL and MySQL. I tested this on http://sqlfiddle.com.

This is the query. It may not be the most efficient, but it's fairly straightforward.

```
SELECT
    EN3.companyProfileId
  , EN3.maxCreateTimestamp
  , EN3.secondMaxCreateTimestamp
  , EN4.engagementScore newestEngagementScore
  , EN5.engagementScore secondNewestEngagementScore
  , EN4.engagementScore - EN5.engagementScore AS engagementDifference
  , 100.0 * (EN4.engagementScore - EN5.engagementScore) / EN5.engagementScore percentDifference
FROM
(
    SELECT
        EN1.companyProfileId
      , EN2.maxCreateTimestamp
      , MAX(EN1.createTimestamp) secondMaxCreateTimestamp
    FROM
        engagement EN1
    INNER JOIN
        (
        SELECT
            companyProfileId
          , MAX(createTimestamp) maxCreateTimestamp
        FROM
            engagement
        GROUP BY
            companyProfileId
        ) EN2
    ON
        EN1.companyProfileId = EN2.companyProfileId
    AND EN1.createTimestamp != EN2.maxCreateTimestamp
    GROUP BY
        EN1.companyProfileId
      , EN2.maxCreateTimestamp
) EN3
INNER JOIN
    engagement EN4
ON
    EN3.companyProfileId = EN4.companyProfileId
AND EN3.maxCreateTimestamp = EN4.createTimestamp
INNER JOIN
    engagement EN5
ON
    EN3.companyProfileId = EN5.companyProfileId
AND EN3.secondMaxCreateTimestamp = EN5.createTimestamp
WHERE
    100.0 * (EN4.engagementScore - EN5.engagementScore) / (EN5.engagementScore) < -10.00
```

This is the test data set up for MS-SQL.

```
CREATE TABLE engagement (
    companyProfileId INT
  , engagementScore INT
  , createTimestamp DATETIME
);
GO

-- Increased 5%, declined 1%, declined 11%; should be returned for 10%.
INSERT INTO engagement(companyProfileId, engagementScore, createTimestamp) 
SELECT 1000, 7500 * 1.05 * 0.99 * 0.89, DATEADD(dd, -1, GETDATE())
INSERT INTO engagement(companyProfileId, engagementScore, createTimestamp) 
SELECT 1000, 7500 * 1.05 * 0.99, DATEADD(dd, -2, GETDATE())
INSERT INTO engagement(companyProfileId, engagementScore, createTimestamp) 
SELECT 1000, 7500 * 1.05, DATEADD(dd, -3, GETDATE())
INSERT INTO engagement(companyProfileId, engagementScore, createTimestamp) 
SELECT 1000, 7500, DATEADD(dd, -4, GETDATE())

-- Only has one score; should not be returned.
INSERT INTO engagement(companyProfileId, engagementScore, createTimestamp) 
SELECT 1001, 8000, DATEADD(dd, -1, GETDATE())

-- Declined 15%, declined 15%, increased 15%; should not be returned.
INSERT INTO engagement(companyProfileId, engagementScore, createTimestamp) 
SELECT 1002, 6000 * 0.85 * 0.85 * 1.15, DATEADD(dd, -1, GETDATE())
INSERT INTO engagement(companyProfileId, engagementScore, createTimestamp) 
SELECT 1002, 6000 * 0.85 * 0.85, DATEADD(dd, -2, GETDATE())
INSERT INTO engagement(companyProfileId, engagementScore, createTimestamp) 
SELECT 1002, 6000 * 0.85, DATEADD(dd, -3, GETDATE())

-- Increased 5%, declined 1%, declined 11%; should be returned for 10%.
INSERT INTO engagement(companyProfileId, engagementScore, createTimestamp) 
SELECT 1003, 5000 * 1.05 * 0.89, DATEADD(dd, -1, GETDATE())
INSERT INTO engagement(companyProfileId, engagementScore, createTimestamp) 
SELECT 1003, 5000 * 1.05, DATEADD(dd, -2, GETDATE())

-- Declined 9%, declined 9%; should not be returned for 10%.
INSERT INTO engagement(companyProfileId, engagementScore, createTimestamp) 
SELECT 1004, 9250 * 0.91 * 0.91, DATEADD(dd, -1, GETDATE())
INSERT INTO engagement(companyProfileId, engagementScore, createTimestamp) 
SELECT 1004, 9250 * 0.91, DATEADD(dd, -2, GETDATE())
GO
```

The MySQL version of the test data is pretty similar, so I'm omitting most of it, but it's of the form:

```
INSERT INTO engagement(companyProfileId, engagementScore, createTimestamp) 
SELECT 1002, 7500 * 0.85 * 0.85 * 1.15, DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -1 DAY);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this, using window function can solve your problem...

```
SELECT z.companyProfileId,z.engagementScore,z.dropBy,z.createTimestamp FROM (
    SELECT a.companyProfileId,a.engagementScore,CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),(CONVERT(DECIMAL,(a.lastScore-a.engagementScore))/a.lastScore)*100) dropBy, a.createTimestamp,RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY a.companyProfileId ORDER BY a.createTimestamp desc) AS [rank]
    FROM   (
               SELECT a.companyProfileId,
                      a.engagementScore,
                      a.engagementScore -Lag(a.engagementScore, 1) OVER(PARTITION BY a.companyProfileId ORDER BY a.createTimestamp) AS 
                      differ,
                      Lag(a.engagementScore, 1) OVER(PARTITION BY a.companyProfileId ORDER BY a.createTimestamp) AS lastScore,
                      a.createTimestamp
               FROM   engagement a
           ) a
    WHERE  a.differ < 0
    ) z WHERE [rank]=1
```